# How to enable service discovery for eureka client that run in a different machine from the server

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, netflix-eureka, service-discovery

I am using eureka server and client for two projects that talk to each other - one project has many instances that subscribe to the project that runs eureka server. The configuration and the service discovery part work fine when I run the projects locally, but when I push them to a cloud environment the service discovery part does not work anymore. This is my code on the server side:

```
        val regApplications = EurekaServerContextHolder.getInstance().serverContext.registry.applications.registeredApplications
        for (registeredInstance in regApplications) {
            val instances = registeredInstance.instances
            for (instance in instances) {
                path = instance.ipAddr + ":" + instance.port
              
                println("ipaddr:  " + instance.ipAddr + "  port:  " + instance.port)

            }
        }
        return path
    }
```

On the client side I just use the client discovery annotation and the corresponding dependencies in the pom.xml:

```
@EnableDiscoveryClient
```

`Application.properties` for the client:

```
server.port=8761
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
```

`Appliction.yml` for Client:

```
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://transaction-handler.cloud.host/
```

`bootstrap.properties` for client:

```
spring.application.name=a-bootiful-client
```

Comment: Please show us the a`application.properties` for both the services.

Comment: Updated description, thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "service discovery not working"? Can you see in eureka interface if the services correctly registered themselves to eureka?

Comment: They dont. They only do if I run everything at the same machine